# Skip specific lines in text file for processing but return these lines as well in the output

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, for-loop

I have a transcript txt file containing a WEBVTT header, line numbers, timestamps and text lines.

I want to censor only the text lines while leaving the timestamps and line numbers unaffected from censoring. So the timestamp and line number lines should be excluded from censoring (because the number "451" in timestamps or as line number will get censored if I do not skip these lines during censoring).

The transcript looks like this:

```
WEBVTT

1
00:00:00.340 --> 00:00:04.049
Hallo und willkommen. Es gibt Neuigkeiten.

2
00:00:04.839 --> 00:00:05.929
Ich habe mich getrennt.

3
00:00:12.400 --> 00:00:20.949
Von meiner ersten Liebe, von meinem "Chick in the House".

4
00:00:22.132 --> 00:00:26.129
Ich hab jetzt ein mega Wohnmobil und ich bin total happy.
```

My code so far:

```
import re 
from better_profanity import profanity

def censor_transcript():
    """Censor only text lines while leaving timestamp lines and line number
    lines unaffected."""
    # Load transcript file.
    f = open("/home/mareike/transcript.txt", "r")
    my_transcript = f.read()
    f.close()

    # Load censor words from the given profanity wordlist.
    profanity.load_censor_words_from_file("/home/mareike/wordlists/wordlist_deu.txt")

    # Compile regex pattern to find timestamp lines and line number lines.
    timestamp_pattern = re.compile(r"\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+")
    line_num_pattern = re.compile(r"\d+")
    for line in my_transcript.splitlines():
        # Consider only text lines for censoring/skip timestamps and line numbers.
        if re.match(timestamp_pattern, line):
            pass
        elif re.match(line_num_pattern, line):
            pass
        else:
            # Censor profanities with better_profanity method.
            censored = profanity.censor(line)
            print(censored)
    return censored

# Call function.
censor_transcript()
```

With this code, only the censored text lines are printed, but I want this function to give back the whole transcript (i.e. with line numbers, timestamps, and censored text).

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this? How might I add the timestamps and line numbers to the `censored` output?

I am thankful for every hint!

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm trying to understand the issue correctly. Would you like to create a new file excluding the censored lines ?
If thats the requirement, then you could initialise an empty list and then instead of passing when a timestamp or line_num_pattern is found, you should append the lines to the list. You can then write the list to a txt file. 
Please let me know if there is a gap in my understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping all the lines, and only if the line does not contain a digit or a timestamp like format (for which I think you can just `\d` to not match a line with a digit) you pass.

But this line at the end `censored = profanity.censor(line)` overwrites the variable in each iteration, and the method just returns that last overwritten variable.

If you want to keep all lines, you can use a list and add all the lines to it, also the unmodified ones in the parts where you `pass`, and afterwards return the list, or join the lines on a newline.

The updated part of the code might look like:

```
result = []
for line in my_transcript.splitlines():
    if re.match(timestamp_pattern, line):
        result.append(line)
        pass
    elif re.match(line_num_pattern, line):
        result.append(line)
        pass
    else:
        censored = profanity.censor(line)
        result.append(censored)
        return censored
return "\n".join(result)
```

**Note** that you have to escape the dot in the regex to match it literally.

```
^\d+:\d+:\d+\.\d+
```